# React native not working properly on mobile web browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I have a react native project(expo) which is working correclty on expoGo but when I run it on the mobile browser(localhost:) it displays everything on the page but won't be able to do the onClick event, so it is not possible to use, to navigate and to populate the fields. Is there any help?

NB: as long as I press on a field immediately after page reload it works on that field, but then still won't be able to do anything else

Comment: open console, are there any error logs ?

Comment: can you provide a video of it? it's hard to guess it just from this texts

Comment: @jted95 can’t add it. Basically imagine instagram app on iOS working but when you go to mobile browser and search for m.instagram.com it only display the page correctly but not possible to navigate or to click any of the clickable button on the page

Comment: @DamiaoRod, i see. so the `onPress` in `Pressable` or `TouchableOpacity` doesn't work in the web right?

Comment: @jted95 basically yes, it only works when deploy the web app for seconds then stop working.

Comment: @DamiaoRod, I see. Honestly, this will be hard to solve without seeing any more details like code, your log, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.